# Volley POST REQUEST error 500

Tags: android, android-volley

**JSON:**

```
{
  "isRegistrationSuccess":"true"
}
```

This what my backend should provide while user successfully register in system. I am sending Name, Email and Password as parameters. I am getting 500 error.

```
/Volley: [188] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://100.100.202.200/mobile/register?name=admin&email=admin@nomail.com&password=admin123
```

Although, I can see the user information in my backend. Here is my code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url_to_parse = getLink(name,email,password).trim();
        StringRequest stringReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_to_parse, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response){
                try{
                    Log.d("Response",response);
                    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
                    boolean isLoginSuccess = Boolean.parseBoolean(obj.getString(0));
                    if(isLoginSuccess){
                       onSignupSuccess();
                    }else{
                        onSignupFailed();
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    onSignupFailed();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               onSignupFailed();
                Log.e("Error",String.valueOf(error.getMessage()));
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringReq);
```

I am not sure what is wrong I am doing here? How can I solve it?

Comment: Plaintext passwords? Really? I'll assume this is a learning exercise and you'll change that later?

Comment: Anyways, so you understand that a 500 error means there's a problem with the server? Find the logs and provide them in the question, please with an [edit]. And side comment; you aren't POST-ing data correctly, you are essentially making a GET request with query parameters

Comment: @cricket_007 it is a registration, not a login call.

Comment: why are you passing parameters in the url, if you are using a post request?

Comment: @njzk2 The database doesn't need to know a plaintext password. It shouldn't ever leave the client. Login or Registration. That's my point.

Comment: @Frank: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

POST data is given in a protected Map  getParams () and not the URL:

```
@Override
protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("parametr1","value1");
    params.put("parametr2","value2");
    params.put("parametr3","value3");
    return params;
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return params;
}
```

Fix your url and use JsonObjectRequest

Answer (score -2):

You want to parse a array into a boolean, you have to loop through the array like this:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("example");
                            if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                                  
                                    boolean isLoginSuccess = Boolean.parseBoolean(jo.getString("exampleString"));
                                }  
                            }
```

Comment: How does this solve an internal server error? And you are looping over an empty array

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think his problem is a server error, and if it is a server error his code is wrong, I just corrected it

Comment: sure, but if he manages to fix his server problems with your instruction he is going to have another problem - btw sorry cricket_007 I'm new here and I have to learn to read the problem right

Comment: Agreed :) Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll get it eventually